# Why is the divergence of this vector field 0? And why can't I prove it using the divergence theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

This is a question from *Stuart Calculus* 7ed, section 16.9:

"Verify that ${\rm div}({\bf E})=0$ for the electric field ${\bf E}=\frac{\epsilon Q}{\|\bf x\|^{3}}{\bf x}$ ."

We can rewrite:
$$
{\bf E}=\epsilon Q\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}{\bf i}+\epsilon Q\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}{\bf j}+\epsilon Q\frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}{\bf k}
$$

It's easy to prove it using the definition of divergence

$$
{\rm div}({\bf E})=\nabla \boldsymbol{\cdot}{\bf E}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\epsilon Qx}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\epsilon Qy}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\epsilon Qz}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}=\epsilon Q\frac{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)-3x^2-3y^2-3z^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{5/2}}=0
$$

I found this to be a weird result, given that [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LDye.png) is the plotted vector field, and it very clearly "diverges" (as in the all vectors point outward) from the origin. Am I misinterpretating the vector plot or the definition of divergence?

I also tried to prove it using the divergence theorem.

Let S be the surface of a sphere of radius 1 with normal vector **n**, and R the region limited by this sphere. From the divergence theorem:

$$
\iint _{S}\left({\bf E}\boldsymbol{\cdot} {\bf n}\right)dS=\iiint _{R}\left( \nabla\boldsymbol{\cdot}{\bf E}\right)dV
$$

$$
\nabla\boldsymbol{\cdot}{\bf E}=0 \therefore \iiint _{R}\left( \nabla\boldsymbol{\cdot}{\bf E}\right)dV=0 \therefore \iint _{S}\left({\bf E}\boldsymbol{\cdot} {\bf n}\right)dS=0
$$

However, I solved the surface integral and found the result $4\pi \epsilon Q$. Am I just making a mistake? I can't figure it out where the mistake is in my solving process.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its divergence is $0$ everywhere except the origin because the divergence before subtracting all of the terms was not defined there. The divergence for that vector field can be defined as a Dirac delta at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t make a mistake. The mistake is in the sloppy problem statement. It should say that you should prove that the divergence is $0$ *except at the origin*.   The divergence of the electric field is proportional to the charge density, so for a point charge it’s a delta distribution at the origin. So there’s no contradiction between your two results: Away from the singularity at the origin, the divergence is $0$, but if you integrate the flux over a surface that encloses the origin you pick up the delta contribution from the singularity at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Divergence is the extent to which the fields acts locally as if radiating from a point there. A point charge's electric field only behaves as such at that point. That's the obvious intuition. We want something that can integrate over space to a finite non-zero value, yet vanish except at one point, so it will have to be proportional to the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). The proportionality constant will be whatever makes the surface integral come out right. Indeed, $\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}=4\pi\epsilon Q\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{x})$.